# monekeyrunner can not return the value of "getProperty" and "getSystemProperty"

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

When i wrote a python script to use *monkeyrunner*, I found that the script can not get the return value of `getProperty`, which I want. The script only gets the `None` result.

Here is python code where I want the return value of `getProperty`:

```py
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

# import module
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyImage

# connect service 
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

print device.getProperty("build.ID")
print device.getProperty("activity") 
print device.getSystemProperty('build.version.sdk')
```

And the result is `None`.

I don't know what is wrong.
Kindly review and give feedback.

Here is the running result:

[image]

Here is the whole script that I code:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

# import module
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, 
MonkeyImage

# connect service
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

# screenshot
result = device.takeSnapshot()
result.writeToFile('E:\\Taskmanagetest_1\\testresult\\Test_001.jpg','jpg')

# install apk  
device.installPackage('E:\\Taskmanagetest_1\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\app-debug.apk')  

# sleep
MonkeyRunner.sleep(5)

# screenshot
result = device.takeSnapshot()
result.writeToFile('E:\\Taskmanagetest_1\\testresult\\Test_002.jpg','jpg')

# print device.getProperty("am.current.comp.package")

print('Install Success!')

# test
device.startActivity(component="com.example.samuel_soon.taskmanagetest_1/.Ma"
                           "inActivity")
MonkeyRunner.sleep(5)

result = device.takeSnapshot()
result.writeToFile('E:\\Taskmanagetest_1\\testresult\\Test_003.jpg','jpg')

device.touch(520,520,'DOWN_AND_UP')

MonkeyRunner.sleep(5)
result = device.takeSnapshot()
result.writeToFile('E:\\Taskmanagetest_1\\testresult\\Test_004.jpg','jpg')

print device.getProperty("build.ID")
print device.getProperty("activity")
print device.getSystemProperty('build.version.sdk')

device.removePackage("com.example.samuel_soon.taskmanagetest_1")
print('Remove Success!')
result = device.takeSnapshot()
result.writeToFile('E:\\Taskmanagetest_1\\testresult\\Test_005.jpg','jpg')
```

Comment: Providing code samples using screenshots may appear nice to you. But you should think about including source code in your question (like the first code sample). By doing so, it makes the error messages and source code parseable by search engines which may bring more people to see you question.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for your remind

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to generate a script that you can edit and add the `print` statements

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (C) 2013-2018  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2019-03-26 by Culebra v15.5.1
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
"""


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)

print device.getProperty("ro.build.id")
print device.getTopActivityName()
print device.getSystemProperty("ro.build.version.sdk")
```

and when executed prints the expected values

```
OSM1.180201.007
com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity
27
```